# python scraping extract onclick attribute

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I want to extract only `http` value from `onclick` in the result below

Something like this:

```
http://14.63.194.48:1935/fado/fado7.stream/playlist.m3u8

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = urlopen("http://smantv.net/tv/ajax.tv_channel.php")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

nameList = bsObj.find_all("",{"class":"spo_wc_active"})
for name in nameList:
print (name)
```

RESULT

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:post_chtitle('', 'http://14.63.194.48:1935/fado/fado7.stream/playlist.m3u8', '[MLB] 워싱턴 vs 애틀랜타 (한국어중계)', '');" class="spo_wc spo_h spo_wc_active">방송보기</a>
```

Comment: By `http` value do you mean `http://14.63.194.48:1935/fado/fado7.stream/playlist.m3u8`?

Answer (score 1):

So your code is

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen("http://smantv.net/tv/ajax.tv_channel.php")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

nameList = bsObj.find_all("", {"class": "spo_wc_active"})
for name in nameList: print (name)
```

Which works OK.

The output is

```
<a class="spo_wc spo_h spo_wc_active" href="#" onclick="javascript:post_chtitle('', 'http://14.63.194.48:1935/fado/fado72.stream/playlist.m3u8', '[MLB]  밀워키 vs 샌디에이고', '');">방송보기</a>
<a class="spo_wc spo_h spo_wc_active" href="#" onclick="javascript:post_chtitle('', 'http://14.63.194.48:1935/fado/fado79.stream/playlist.m3u8', '[UEFA EL]  세비야 FC [white] vs FK 잘기리스 빌뉴스 [green]', '');">방송보기</a>
```

If you print the nameList (which is actually a bs4.element.ResultSet object) itself instead of iterating through it you get

```
[<a class="spo_wc spo_h spo_wc_active" href="#" onclick="javascript:post_chtitle('', 'http://14.63.194.48:1935/fado/fado72.stream/playlist.m3u8', '[MLB]  밀워키 vs 샌디에이고', '');">방송보기</a>, <a class="spo_wc spo_h spo_wc_active" href="#" onclick="javascript:post_chtitle('', 'http://14.63.194.48:1935/fado/fado79.stream/playlist.m3u8', '[UEFA EL]  세비야 FC [white]    vs FK 잘기리스 빌뉴스 [green]', '');">방송보기</a>]
```

So if not empty, then you can iterate it, like

```
print(nameList[0])

<a class="spo_wc spo_h spo_wc_active" href="#" onclick="javascript:post_chtitle('', 'http://14.63.194.48:1935/fado/fado32.stream/playlist.m3u8', '[PAR D1]  클루브 솔 데 아메리카    vs  인데펜디엔테 FBC', '');">방송보기</a>
```

The same way you can get this line converted to a string. The split that string and finally strip the quotation, I'll show it in interactive python console, like

```
>>> parts = str(nameList[0]).split(', ')
>>> parts
['<a class="spo_wc spo_h spo_wc_active" href="#" onclick="javascript:post_chtitle(\'\'', "'http://14.63.194.48:1935/fado/fado32.stream/playlist.m3u8'", "'[PAR D1]  클루브 솔 데 아메리카\tvs\t인데펜디엔테 FBC'", '\'\');">방송보기</a>']
```

so `parts` now is an actual list of plain strings, now you can get what you want

```
>>> print(parts[1].strip("'"))
http://14.63.194.48:1935/fado/fado32.stream/playlist.m3u8
```

of course, if you have more than one result, then you need to wrap these step in loop(s)

if you fancy another way, I've just found that you can actually get the string out of it without converting anything, like:

```
>>> nameList[0]['onclick']
"javascript:post_chtitle('', 'http://14.63.194.48:1935/fado/fado32.stream/playlist.m3u8', '[PAR D1]  클루브 솔 데 아메리카\tvs\t인데펜디엔테 FBC', '');"
>>> type(nameList[0]['onclick'])
<class 'str'>
```

so once more, this time including the quotation to the split()

```
>>> nameList[0]['onclick'].split("', '")[1]
'http://14.63.194.48:1935/fado/fado32.stream/playlist.m3u8'
```

#### Complete code with loop

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen("http://smantv.net/tv/ajax.tv_channel.php")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

nameList = bsObj.find_all("", {"class": "spo_wc_active"})

url_list = []
for name in nameList:
    parts = str(name).split(', ')
    url = parts[1].strip("'")
    url_list.append(url)
```

So now you have `url_list`, a list of 0-n URLs which match your original pattern

You can get the items in the list iterating through it

```
for url in url_list:
    print(url)
```

Comment: Thanks to Gergely M for your correct answer. You gave me the exact answer I wanted.

I had only one month to study Python and it was so hard.

Please help me a lot in the future!

Thank you again.

Comment: The following Python output shows the same value. I want to loop this part >> parts = str (nameList [0]). Split (',') <<, what should I do?

I've done this like a fool.
parts = str (nameList [0]). split (',')
parts1 = str (nameList [1]). split (',')
parts2 = str (nameList [2]). split (',')

Comment: I've updated the answer and added the complete code with the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for kindly giving us the correct answer.

I need to do scrapping with Python and save it to the database automatically in the next month.

I would like to refer you to Gergely M even if I pay the fee.

Please email me at dpott.com.agency@gmail!

Thank you again.